# Securely login into website from a different server?

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication

Here's the thing:

I have Website A in Server 1, a CakePHP 2 based website without any kind of login system.

I also have Website B in Server 2, another CakePHP website which **has** its login system (uses CakePHP's Auth for more details if it matters), with a login form in first page where users can enter login/password to access it.

So now what I need to do is to add a login form in website A that logs users into website B (as if they had used the form in website B).

Is that possible? If so, what approach should I take to do that securely? (By that I mean without plainly exposing the users credentials).

Comment: I don't get what is the problem. If it's just a standard login, you just can connect to Website B database and login with those credentials

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're doing this so that you can go between multiple sites, but only login once?  I've come up with a way to do this, provided that the sites share domains, but are hosted on different subdomains by getting them to share session. The reason this only works on websites that share domains is because two completely unrelated websites cannot share cookies, which is necessary to get them to share session.

Note that since your goal is to make the two servers completely share their sessions, you will encounter some problems, like for example, flashmessages for one site will appear on both.  I ended up extending the Session component so that it would automatically append to all session variables with a prefix to specify which server the session variable belongs to.

Here's an outline of the steps:

1. The login server will need to be able to host shared sessions, probably via memcache's session save handler, which you will need to install on both your servers.  See more here: http://www.dotdeb.org/2008/08/25/storing-your-php-sessions-using-memcached/
2. The login server's site will need all the regular stuff for a login system, but you also need to set the server up so that it will use the shared memcache session instead of the normal way of saving session.  Example once you have memcache installed, add to its php.ini file:

   `session.save_handler = memcache`

   `session.save_path = "tcp://[login server ip]:11211"`
3. The other server's site will also need to use the shared memcache session stored on the login server, so config its php.ini the same way you did for  your login server.  Then, set up the Auth component on this site so that it will require logins, but for actually logging in, redirect them back to your login server.
4. On both servers, in bootstrap.php, add the line `ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.' . ROOT_DOMAIN);`  Where root domain is the root domain both of them have.  So if you were using test.com and subdomain.test.com, ROOT_DOMAIN would be "test".  This way, the websites will also share their session cookies.
5. Make absolutely sure both servers are set to the same time.  If their times don't match, you'll likely randomly lose your session because one of the servers will think the session is much older than the other server, and so it will delete it because it thinks the session is too old.